# i want to check if the document library exists or not in sharepoint

Tags: document-library

I'm new to SharePoint and I have a project to check with c# whether or not a document library exists from a given url, using folder level and document library name as parameters.

Could any one help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

If your have a valid SPWeb in `web`, and document library title in `libTitle` variables, `return (web.Lists.TryGetList(libTitle) != null)` will return `true` only if that document library exists

Comment: thank you for your response,but i just have weburl and library name, where url will be like url/server/libname/folder/folder1.   so i need to check the library exists or not.i tried using your code but its throwing error